# How to call Button_Click from another Class in c#?

Tags: c#, class, button, click

I have a class `Class1`:

```
public partial class Class1 {
     public void Button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) 
     {
          //do something
     }
}
```

and a second class `Class2`:

```
public partial class Class2 {
     //some Code
     //Call Button1_Click from Class1
     // some more code
}
```

How can I call the Button1_Click of Class1 in Class2?

Comment: Short answer: you don't. Longer answer: move the functionality from the click even into a method you can easily call.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass Class1 into Class2 via the constructor e.g.

```
class Class1
{
    Class2 c2 = new Class2(this);
}

class Class2
{
    Class1 C2;

    public Class2(Class1 _class1){
        C2 = _class1;
    }
}
```

and then for your button press simply do

```
public void PressClass1Button()
{
     C2.Button1_Click();
}
```

I'm sorry I haven't checked the actual syntax as I'm at work but this is the basic concept I normally use for this kind of problem.

It's a messy/simple solution and probably not the best!

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to delegate it , firing up event that will auto call the button click

example :

```
private void delegate_You_Create(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs args)
{
   Button1_Click(sender, args);
}
```

you can read about delegate [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_delegates.htm)

Answer (score 0):

A button click event is there to do what it says on the tin - handle the button click. The enclosed functionality is simply you saying "I'd like to do this when this happens".

For example

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) 
{
  // Do the stuff I want to do when Button1 is clicked
}
```

Extending this example to use a second button that does exactly the same you could add a second click event and duplicate the code like this

```
public void Button2_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) 
{
  // Do the stuff I want to do when Button1 is clicked
}
```

However, a better approach, avoiding the duplication, would be to pull the button stuff out into a method and then do this

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) 
{
  DoButtonStuff();
}

public void Button2_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) 
{
  DoButtonStuff();
}

private void DoButtonStuff()
{
    // Do the stuff I want to do when my buttons are clicked
}
```

Extending this further you could make `DoButtonStuff` public and call it from elsewhere as you would with any other method.

This approach is better because you're capturing the thing you're interested in - the `DoButtonStuff` - and not the thing that caused it to happen - the button click.

---

EDIT - In response to your static question.

You have a few options -

You could make `DoButtonStuff` static then do something like this

```
// Class1
static void DoButtonStuff() { ... }

// Class2
Class1.DoButtonStuff();
```

You could make DoButtonStuff public then instantiate Class1 inside Class2 then do something like this

```
// Class1
public void DoButtonStuff() { ... }

// Class2
Class1 myClass1 = new Class1();

myClass1.DoButtonStuff();
```

You could pull DoButtonStuff out into a separate class and call it from there something like this

```
// MethodClass
public void DoButtonStuff() { ... }

// Class1
MethodClass myMethodClass = new MethodClass();
myMethodClass.DoButtonStuff();
```

You could do the same in Class2.

The first option is probably the simplest and may well be the best for you.

The second option is rarely a good idea because it couples your two classes in a way that they almost certainly shouldn't be.

The third option is probably the best for more complex problems, particularly if `DoButtonStuff` doesn't involve updating the UI - e.g. a save operation.

Comment: my `DoButtonStuff` has to be `static` in order to call if from my Class2